# Spring Database Connection Configuration Process

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, glassfish

This is probably and extremely easy question for some of you, although I require assistance in understanding the process of setting up a database connection between my Spring MVC application, which is currently running on Glassfish 4 and MySQL. What are the steps in doing this? I have outlined my ideas below, however I am still left unclear with this process.

So far I have created a JDBC Connection Pool within the Glassfish 4 administration panel and connected successfully with the defined parameters; ping returns successful. Do I need to create a JNDI DataSource now, because I believe this is required to connect to the Database Connection Pool?

If this is the correct steps thus far; What steps are performed next? My assumption is that the web.xml needs to be configured so that it links to the JNDI DataSource? Is this correct?

Your assistance in this manner will be appreciated.

**[UPDATED]**

I have figured this all out and now everything is performing as expected. However, I ran into one implication along the way which I did not quite understand why the connection did not want to function at one point.

This was my configuration within the web.xml where I faced issues with:

`<resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/application</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>`

I was receiving all types of errors when attempting to pull records from one of my tables. The error message was something along the lines of:

> "javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource
>   invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection.
>   Cause: Connection could not be allocated because:
>   java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on
>   port 1527"

Although I found the solution to this where I included the `<mapped-name>` element within the parent `<resource-ref>` element in the web.xml

This is what the file looked after I had applied the update:

`<resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/application</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        <mapped-name>jdbc/application</mapped-name>
</resource-ref>`

What does the `<mapped-name>` node do which allows me to establish this connection correctly? My assumption is that is finds and maps it against the correct JNDI record, although I thought that this mapping was performed by the: `<re-ref-name>` element that was originally defined.

Please advice, a explanation to this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do I need to create a JNDI DataSource now?

This is not mandatory but also favored. You can access your db like an object. (jndi/YourDatasource)

If this is the correct steps thus far; What steps are performed next? My assumption is that the web.xml needs to be configured so that it links to the JNDI DataSource? Is this correct?

App server can be different in this situation. web.xml is a choice or sun-resources.xml